# Scheduling Python scripts in Google App Engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Can we schedule normal Python scripts using Google App Engine?
Or can it only be used to schedule webapps?

Problem - I have a couple of Python scripts running in Google Compute Engine and want to schedule them using the cron service in Google App Engine.

Comment: I used for a similar situation this pattern. https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine.I think should be useful for your use case. But you need pub/sub in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The GAE cron is fundamentally just a scheduler for HTTP GET requests:

- from the [standard environment doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron):

> A cron job invokes a URL, using an HTTP GET request, at a given time
>   of day. A cron job request is subject to the same limits as those for
>   [push task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Task_Queue).

- from the [flexible environment doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml):

> A cron job will invoke a URL, using an HTTP GET request, at a given
>   time of day. An HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 60
>   minutes, but is [subject to the same limits as other HTTP
>   requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits).

You cannot directly invoke plain/regular python scripts from the GAE cron itself, see [Google cloud app.yaml cron.yaml for python script not working but no log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856414/google-cloud-app-yaml-cron-yaml-for-python-script-not-working-but-no-log/44866943#44866943).

But you can invoke such scripts from *inside* a valid GAE cron handler (if they meet the respective GAE restrictions). The scripts would be running on GAE, though technically flexible environment GAE is really GCE under the hood.

If you want to keep the scripts running on GCE as they are now you'd need a way to trigger them from GAE.