# Google cloud app.yaml cron.yaml for python script not working but no log

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I'm trying to use Google cloud's cron to run my Python script at a time interval. I followed instructions from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron to set up everything and the task shows up in my Task Queue for cron jobs, but when I click run the status says failed. Nothing shows up in the log either (when I click "View" under log it says "no entries found" so I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. I looked at some similar questions and it seems like I should be using more handlers but I'm not sure when handlers are needed. The script (scraper.py) is in the same directory as cron.yaml and app.yaml and my code is below. Any help appreciated!

scraper.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: daily update
  url: /
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: scraper.app
```

Comment: In the Task Queue viewer, click the "cron jobs" tab.  To the left of the "Run" button is a "View" button.  What does the error show?  If it's a 404, then you aren't handling the url properly.  If a 500, then some code error.  How are you handling the urls in `scraper`?   And, you probably want a wildcard url handler in `app.yaml`:  ` - url: /.*` instead of ` - url: /`

Comment: When I click "View" it says "no entries found" so I don't see any errors logged, just that the status is failed. Everything in scraper I just used pip install. I changed it to the wildcard url and it's still not working, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a plain python script like your `scraper.py` directly from the GAE cron, at least not with its current content.

You need a basic GAE app skeleton in there, with a handler for the cron job's URL. Remember that the GAE cron job is simply a GET request for that URL, which your app needs to handle. That handler is where you'd place the code you want to be executed.

You can find a sample skeleton in the [Hello World code review](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart#hello_world_code_review).