# Python - post in firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, schedule

I want to make a python script that serves as a backend for my firebase application.

I would like to post, at a specific time, an object in firebase. but it is published 3,4 or 5 times.. while I only want a single record of jobStoreAllum () for example.

Thank you for your help

```
 from time import sleep
 import time
 import datetime
 from firebase import firebase
 import urllib2, urllib, httplib
 import json
 import os 
 from functools import partial
 firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://plante-.firebaseio.com/', None)
 import schedule


 def jobAllum():
     x=1
     y=True
     firebase.put("/Interuptors/Elec01", "/value", x)
     firebase.put("/Interuptors/Elec01", "/state", y)

 def jobStoreAllum():
     dateString = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
     y=True
     data = {"State": y,"Horodate":datetime.datetime.now().strftime(dateString) }
     firebase.post('/Storage/Journee', data)


 while True:
     Hallum= firebase.get("/Autom/Prog1/Hallum", None)
     schedule.every().day.at(Hallum).do(jobAllum)
     schedule.every().day.at(Hallum).do(jobStoreAllum)
     schedule.run_pending()
     time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cloud Scheduler.
Make sure you terminate your function returning a value.
And watchout for function timeout, default is 1 minute and maximum is 9 minutes. 
You will have to enable Billing for the project and you have 3 jobs free per month, over 3 are charged $0.10/job, not execution.

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54264520/5482999I)

Comment: You still can get away with it by using creating only 1 job in Scheduler.
I asked support and they were quite clear to point out that you pay by 'Created Job', not execution.
Or you can create a cron job in your computer(That's how I started), being the only downside that your computer will have to be on at the times the cron job is scheduled.